# Desert Wanderings bring…Ciphers? Part 2

Tags: riddle, cipher, no-computers

<sup>Part 1 can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42477/desert-wanderings-bring-ciphers-part-1)

Part 3 can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43971/desert-wanderings-bring-ciphers-part-3)</sup>
As you utter your answer, along with its reasoning of course, the Sphinx clearly looks disappointed.

> You are unfortunately… Correct. Clearly I made that too easy. 
>  Well then, I guess I’ll just have to make the next one harder.

Once again, Azerty begins to write, only this time she’s not writing numbers but writing… Dancing men? How is that a riddle or a cipher?

[image: Riddle]
[image: Riddle]
[image: Riddle]
[image: Riddle]

As she finishes writing, Azerty says,

> This is my riddle and not one heard from some stranger. 
>  So be sure to give credit where credit is due.

**Author's Note**: If this proves to be too hard I'll remove the [no-computers]

Comment: "*This is my riddle and not one heard from some stranger.
So be sure to give credit where credit is due.*" - flagged for plagiarism :-P

Comment: How about a text form for those relying on visual aid?

Comment: **Related** - [Sherlock Holmes Dancing Men](http://luthorien.altervista.org/Tools/images/dancing.jpg)

Comment: @Matsmath I would put one up, I've no idea how to go about it in this case.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil no compters :P

Comment: @dcfyj, just an image. I doubt there are any cipher translators for men to words for this anyway

Comment: Just replace your figures with alphabet.

Comment: @Matsmath it's a fairly long riddle that appears to be using a substitution cipher.  I'm leaving the hard work to Beastly Gerbil as its a pain going through and finding all the matching men.  The actual cipher appears fairly trivial with the length of the riddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The riddle is as follows

> AZERTY'S RIDDLE

I think this part

> HEAR ME SHOUT ALOUD,
> FOR I AM QUITE PROUD.
> A LEADER OF MANY,
> WHERE FOLKS GET QUITE SWEATY.

references:

> A Lion based on common Gym logos?

And this part

> WHILE I PRODUCE MILK,
> I'M NOT OF THAT ILK.
> SOME OF US ARE FROM CRAGS,
> DON'T MISTAKE US FOR STAGS.

is:

> a goat, producing milk, horned, and sometimes craggy

This part

> MUSCLE AND FANGS,
> I'M IN NO GANGS.
> FEW OF US HAVE TOXINS,
> TO PUT YOU IN COFFINS.

is:

> a serpent, sometimes poisonous, always fanged, primarily muscle.

Which makes this part

> COMBINE MY THREE,
> AND YOU'LL GET ME.
> STRAIGHT OUT OF ANCIENT LORE,
> I'LL BURN YOU TO YOUR CORE.

a

> Chimera, which had a Dragon, Goat, and Lion head, and Serpent tail.

Comment: Good job, This is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this image](http://luthorien.altervista.org/Tools/images/dancing.jpg) from the Sherlock Holmes Dancing Man Cipher

I decode the riddle as

(After / I have copied from @Sconibulus who solved it while I was out but I'll add it in so the answer is complete)

> **Azerty's Riddle**
> Hear me shout aloud
> For I am quite proud
> /
> A leader of many
> Where folks get quite sweaty
> While I produce milk,
> I'm not of that ilk,
> Some of us are from crags
> Don't mistake us for stags
> Muscle and fangs
> I'm in no gangs
> Few of us have toxins
> To put you in coffins
> Combine my three
> And you'll get me
> Straight out of ancient lore,
> I'll burn you to your core

Like I said @Sconibulus already got the answer but I'll just add it here:

> The first section gives a lion, as seen on Gym logos
> The second section gives a goat, milk-producing, horned and living in the mountains
> The third section gives serpent, muscle based, fanged and sometimes poisonous
> The final answer is [**Chimera**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(mythology)), after the fourth section tells us to combine these and the Chimera is a lion, goat and serpent hybrid and is a mythical creature

Comment: By no-computers I meant don't look up anything either :(

Comment: I'm decoding it only using word now @dcfyj, and using what I have to decode the rest

Comment: Ah ok, At least there's that. Although the title could've been deciphered without the lookup too.