# What does this text mean?

Tags: cipher, language

[image]

Please help me decipher the text

Comment: Is this a puzzle?  Is there any context for the text.

Comment: Is this a translation request, or is this actually a cipher?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to use an non english language and is simply a translation not a puzzle

Comment: It's an old Chinese proverb that translates to "Man who run behind car get exhausted."

Comment: There aren't enough symbols for this to actually be a language with symbols like this, it looks like it's using these symbols to encipher the latin alphabet.

Comment: this is not a translation.  the puzzle is a simple substitution cipher, only made difficult by the choice of representation of symbols.  transcribing those characters to something practical to work with is tedium and pain, and I don't recommend future puzzlers to do this sort of thing...

Comment: Hello and welcome to Puzzling.SE. I am sorry, but *no story, no upvotes on this site*. See some other similar, highly praised questions http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42663/desert-wanderings-bring-ciphers-part-2 to get some idea on how to improve your presentation.

Comment: @Matsmath: That is not true at all. Please stop spreading misinformation.

Comment: Hey, @Matsmath, I've noticed a lot of your comments are very harshly worded. Would you mind dialing back your bluntness a _lot_?

Comment: @Emrakul atDeusovi on the weekend I might initiate some discussion on meta about *How to make new users feel welcome to this site*. I have some thoughts I would like to propose and I hope that we will get some canonical answers to share with new users in the future. I also plan on making an argument for the need of a higher tolerance towards dryer puzzles which are borderline math/cryptohraphy/computational intensive, and, perhaps, propose an [advanced-cryptography] or similar tag to find a home for questions which require more sophisticated techniques than simple substitution. Happy puzzling!

Comment: @Norbert - I'm pretty sure the correct answer has been given.  It's customary to accept the "best" answer as correct based on some rational criteria (most correct, most complete, first to answer correctly, etc.), or if there's not a correct answer given to provide some further guidance (comments with pointers in the right direction, additional hinting, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

I transcribed the characters of the original to unique symbols, then did a simple substitution cipher on the result.  The original text has a couple spaces missing, so literally translates to

> FROM THE ENTRANCE MAKE YOUR WAY PAST THE FIRST EASILYNEGOTIATED FALL. JUST PAST THE LARGE PASSAGE TO YOURRIGHT IS A PASSAGE TO THE LEFT. FOLLOW THIS AND TURN RIGHT. THE CACHE IS BEHIND THE DEADS HIGH UP TO THE RIGHT

If anyone's interested, I started by picking an arbitrary ascii character that the original symbol vaguely reminded me of, giving me this mess:

> ```
> L 2 H t r 3 Z E r E + 3 2 B + D E r t B K E r i H l 2
> r A B i r M B h 3 r 3 Z E r L m 2 h 3 r E B h m b i +
> E P H 3 m B 3 E \$ r L B b b . r j l h 3 r n B h 3 r 3
> Z E r b B 2 P E r n B h h B P E r 3 H r i H l 2 2 m P
> Z 3 r m h r B r n B h h B P E r 3 H r 3 Z E r b E L 3
> . r L H b b H A r 3 Z m h r B + \$ r 3 l 2 + r 2 m P Z
> 3 . r 3 Z E r A B A Z E r m h r 8 E Z m + \$ r 3 Z E r
> \$ E B \$ h r Z m P Z r l n r 3 H r 3 Z E r 2 m P Z 3
> ```

from there it was figuring out the substitution.

> a choice of "r" or "3" for space, which ended up being "r"; then "r 3 Z E r" -> " the "; then the rest started falling into place.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a monoalphabetic substitution cipher, I've transliterated as best I'm able

> ```
>  First I assumed that the bold, very common element was space.
> ABCD EFG GHEBIHJG DIKG LMNB
>  OIL PIKE EFG ARBKE GIKRSLH
> GTCERIEGU AISS, VNKE PIKE E
> FG SIBTG PIKKITG EC LCNBBRT
> FE RK I PIKKITG EC EFG SGAE
> , ACSSCO EFRK IHY ENBH BRTF
> E, EFG JIJFG RK QGFRHU EFG 
> UGIUK FRTF NX EC EFG BRTFE
> ```

After a few adjustments for possible misspellings, I have something that resembles a message:

> from the entrance make your way past the first easily-negotiated fall, just past the large passage to your right is a passage to the left, follow this and turn right, the cache is behind the beads high up to the right

The word I am least sure about is

> BEADS, but not much else seemed to make sense there. (It looked like DEADS)