# Desert Wanderings bring…Ciphers? Part 3

Tags: riddle, cipher

<sup>Part 1 can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42477/desert-wanderings-bring-ciphers-part-1)
Part 2 can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42663/desert-wanderings-bring-ciphers-part-2)</sup>
After painstaking, letter by letter, line by line decryption you think over the riddle a little and then realize what the answer is. You once again tell her the answer and your reasoning as to why it’s the answer.

Azerty’s reply is rather terse. “Correct… you overly intelligent meal. This last riddle should have you scratching your head.”

Now she’s writing a song? How is that a riddle?

[image: Song part 1]

---

[image: Song part 2]

---

[image: Song part 3]

Once finished, Azerty says,

> You read my keys and read my men,
>   Now you will need to read my song.
>   Just remember that I am great,
>   But only when the scale’s not wrong.
>   Using me twice,
>   And using them twice.
>   They go first as small, then as tall,
>   The First is the only exception at all.

After saying telling you that rhyme, Azerty says one final thing before letting you start on her riddle, “I hope you get this wrong, I’m rather tired of eating rabbits and snakes.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a substitution cipher, first I decided that

> Rests were spaces

Then I started fiddling, I saw

> "see me as" repeated several times as an odd construction and a starting point.

Filling in letters as I could, I eventually got the riddle:

> Some see me as terrific,
> Others see me as worldly,
> Still others see me as soiled,
> And I really am dirty!
>
> Some find me wet,
> Others find me cold,
> Still others find me hot,
> And I really am scorching to the core!
>
> I spin around and hide my daughter,
> I spin some more and all goes dark,
> I run in circles with my siblings,
> And I'm not perfect so don't judge!

The answer to this riddle is

> Earth

Clues from the first stanza:

> Terrific->Terra, Worldly->World, Soiled->Soil, Dirty->Dirt

Clues from the second stanza:

> Wet->Ocean, Cold->Poles, Hot->Tropics, Scorching to the core ->Molten insides

Clues from the third stanza:

> Spin->Rotate, Daughter->Moon, Dark->Night, Run in Circles, [Imperfect]-> Orbit, Siblings -> Other Planets

Comment: Correct all around, although not all rests are the same :P. And you missed one of the clues in the last line.